# How to prove that $|e^{i\epsilon e^{i\theta}} - 1|<2\epsilon$?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

How to prove that $$|e^{i\epsilon e^{i\theta}} - 1|<2\epsilon$$ for $\theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$, and small $\epsilon$.

**Attempt** Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta = \ln(2\epsilon +1)$. For $|x| < \delta$.
\begin{align}
|e^{ix e^{i\theta}} - 1| &= |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^ni^n e^{ni\theta}}{n!}|\\
&\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \\
&= e^x-1\\
&< e^\delta -1 \\&= 2\epsilon 
\end{align}

The nonzero root of the equation $\epsilon = \ln(2\epsilon+1)$ is $\epsilon = 1.25645$ before which $\epsilon < \ln(2\epsilon +1)$.
So $x = \epsilon < \delta$ in that interval and $|e^{i\epsilon e^{i\theta}} - 1|<2\epsilon$ holds.

*This is not homework, so please suggest alternative way to demonstrate it. The inequality comes up when evaluating the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$ using complex integration, for $\epsilon$ semicircle near origin.)*

Comment: This is also true because $|e^z - 1| < 2|z|$ for $|z|$ sufficiently small (since $|e^z - 1| \sim |z|$ as $|z| \to 0$).